# PHP: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini on line 107

Tags: php

I am trying to use a proc_open() in my php script to call and execute another php script. The following is the code:

```
$descriptors = array(
 0 => array("pipe","r"),
 1 => array("pipe","w"),
 2 => array("file","./error_log.txt","a")
) ;
$cwd="./";
$process=proc_open('php reversegame.php &', $descriptors,$pipes,$cwd); 
if (is_resource($process)) {
  $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
```

This writes the following error in the error_log.txt

> PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini on line 107

I am new to proc_open, and still trying to get a grasp on the usage of this function. I am actually trying to execute this php script simultaneously while running another script!

Comment: check for "disable_functions" in php.ini file without double quote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901337/php-syntax-error-unexpected-in-etc-php5-cli-php-ini-on-line-107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also faced this error. But this error should not block your script to work. This error comes due to using & operator in INI file (like using error_reporting E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE).

Comment: No, I did not solve the issue as It not block the php scripts. Some settings like error_reporting work in php code too, So its better to remove from ini file and then put in code by using ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE) OR direct function error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE).

Comment: Anyways, heres the solution to that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901337/php-syntax-error-unexpected-in-etc-php5-cli-php-ini-on-line-107

Answer (score 1):

remove `&` from this line

```
$process=proc_open('php reversegame.php ', $descriptors,$pipes,$cwd);
```

Comment: But I want the script to execute in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You might have disabled `proc_open`.

search for `disable_functions` you will see `disable_functions = show_source,system,shell_exec,passthru,exec,phpinfo,proc_open`.

Now change it to `disable_functions =` .

And restart all service and try.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into forking the process using [pcntl_fork()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)

I don't know if this will let you put the other script in the background but you should be able to fork the current thread and then end the current thread with the new forked thread still running.