# PHP: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini on line 107

Tags: php, lamp

I have recently upgraded PHP 5.5.* to PHP 5.6.13.

I need to display all the errors in PHP scripts if there are any. So I have uncommented the following code in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

```
error_reporting
   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
   Development Value: E_ALL
   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

And it is showing the the error "unexpected '&' on line no 107".

I know there is something wrong with in my code and the nothing is displaying in browser while executing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't be uncommenting that, its informational.

If you want all errors comment those lines back out, and look around line 445.

Set `error_reporting = E_ALL`

If you want to see strict mode errors then set `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT`

Make sure you restart your web server after.

One additional note, make sure you only do this for your development system.  You don't want to be spitting out notices and warnings (or even displaying php errors) on a production server.